# HTML5 input type file Error handling

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I build a module to upload files using HTML5 `input type file` element. I found I issue which I need to address/ resolve by showing proper error message:-

1) User selects a file to upload but before pressing uploading button user deleted the source file. now user clicks upload button. In my case nothing happens on UI.

I want to ask that by any means we can know weather file still exists before clicking upload button on input type file element of HTML5.

Pls Note: I am using ember.js

Comment: You can wrap your upload method in `try...catch` to begin with. That would at least allow you to gracefully recover from the error.

Comment: Can you add some code to show exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are uploading the file (Form, XMLHttpRequest, 3rdParty lib), but you could attach an [error event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onerror_dom) to the Element, the form, the XHR element, or event the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) element itself.

If you attached an error handler to the element, you can not handle your use case as the error will be thrown at the very moment when read the file (XHR, FORM send, etc), not when the user picks up the file.

Another option is to prevent this error making the browser read the file "on the fly" by using:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jbgraug/r4o6q10u/2/)

Obviously, if the file is too big you should use a [webworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or check the file size before loading it, so you don't freeze the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'try-catch' approach which allows you to run code and handle errors nicely.

```
try{
 //the code you want to test / run goes here
}catch(e){
 //here is where you handle the error thrown (if any)
 console.log("There was an error!\nError message: " + e.message);
 alert("There was an error!\nError message: " + e.message);
 document.getElementById('errorMessageSpan').innerHTML = "There was an error!\nError message: " + e.message + "";
}
```

Here you are able to catch the error before your application craps itself and present the error to the user or developer (DOM or console).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to give exact reason like: "source file renamed, moved or deleted", if source file is deleted before user clicks on upload button.